# How to include a conditional replace within a LINQ expression?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a LINQ expression, part of which is:

```
Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.Child.RoleName,
                Value = x.Child.RoleName
            })
```

I wish to test the Rolename and if it contains a certain value then return a specific string ie: something like:

```
Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.Child.RoleName.contains("Admin")?"Admin Account":"Not Admin",
                Value = x.Child.RoleName
            })
```

Please excuse the pseudocode, but if it contains "Admin" then return "Admin Account" else "Not Admin" for the "Text" attribute of the dropdown.

What should the code look like?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I also need to add additional tests ie

```
role.Contains("test1))? test1 :  role.Contains("test2")?"Test2":role.Contains("Test3")?"Test3":"Test4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you capitalize the `C` in `Contains`, that should work as you've posted it.

To address your additional question, you have two options.

Option #1:  Stack ?: operators like this:

```
Text = x.Child.RoleName.Contains("Admin") ? "Admin Account" : x.Child.RoleName.Equals("Banana") ? "Banana" : "Something Else"
```

Option #2: Since the above can get ugly quickly, you might prefer to factor out the logic into a separate function. Then you can do:

```
Text = CalculateText(x.Child.RoleName)
```

and

```
String CalculateText(String rolename)
{
    if(rolename.Contains("Admin"))
        return "Admin Account";
    else if(rolename.Equals("Banana"))
        return "Banana";
    else
        return "Something Else";
}
```

Comment: My code was a quess??!! So it seems it is more correct than I thought :)

Comment: Out of interest, how would one extend this to emulate an "else if" scenario? Thanks. See Edit.... to my question

Comment: Addressed. Kindly let me know if you have further questions, or accept the answer as-is. = )

Comment: Great minds think alike, see my edit. Huge thanks. :) Accepting.